# Obscure 'does not implement' compile error

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm writing my first MVC app right now and am creating a new MembershipProvider but am encountering some compile errors that are just plain wrong in the process. Here is my code:

```
public class ProfileProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        protected NameValueCollection Config = null;
        protected new String Name = null;
        protected String _PasswordStrengthRegularExpression = "";
        protected int _MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters = 0;
        protected int _MinRequiredPasswordLength = 0;
        protected String _PasswordFormat = "";
        protected Boolean _RequiresUniqueEmail = false;
        protected int _PasswordAttemptWindow = 0;
        protected int _MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts = 0;
        protected String _ApplicationName = "";
        protected Boolean _RequiresQuestionAndAnswer = false;
        protected Boolean _EnabledPasswordReset = false;
        protected Boolean _EnablePasswordRetrieval = false;

        protected new String PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
        {
            get
            {
                return this._PasswordStrengthRegularExpression;
            }
            set
            {
                this._PasswordStrengthRegularExpression = value;
            }
        }
        public new int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
        {
            get
            {
                return this._MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters;
            }
            set
            {
                this._MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters = value;
            }
        }
        public new int MinRequiredPasswordLength
        {
            get
            {
                return _MinRequiredPasswordLength;
            }
            set
            {
                this._MinRequiredPasswordLength = value;
            }
        }
        public new String PasswordFormat
        {
            get
            {
                return this._PasswordFormat;
            }
            set
            {
                this._PasswordFormat = value;
            }
        }
        public new Boolean RequiresUniqueEmail
        {
            get
            {
                return _RequiresUniqueEmail;
            }
            set
            {
                this._RequiresUniqueEmail = value;
            }
        }
        public new int PasswordAttemptWindow
        {
            get
            {
                return this._PasswordAttemptWindow;
            }
            set
            {
                this._PasswordAttemptWindow = value;
            }
        }
        public new int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
        {
            get
            {
                return this._MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts;
            }
            set
            {
                this._MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts = value;
            }
        }
        public new String ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ApplicationName;
            }
            set
            {
                this._ApplicationName = value;
            }
        }
        public new Boolean RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
        {
            get
            {
                return this._RequiresQuestionAndAnswer;
            }
            set
            {
                this._RequiresQuestionAndAnswer = value;
            }
        }
        public new Boolean EnablePasswordReset
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EnabledPasswordReset;
            }
            set
            {
                this._EnabledPasswordReset = value;
            }
        }
        public new Boolean EnablePasswordRetrieval
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EnablePasswordRetrieval;
            }
            set
            {
                this._EnablePasswordRetrieval = value;
            }
        }
```

And here are my compile errors:

```
Error   5   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.RequiresUniqueEmail.get'    C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   10  'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer.get'  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   1   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression.get'  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   4   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.PasswordFormat.get' C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   6   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.PasswordAttemptWindow.get'  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   3   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.MinRequiredPasswordLength.get'  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   2   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters.get'   C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   7   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts.get' C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   12  'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.EnablePasswordRetrieval.get'    C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   11  'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.EnablePasswordReset.get'    C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   8   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.ApplicationName.set'    C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   9   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.ApplicationName.get'    C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
```

The errors make sense to me; like 'Hey dummy, you need this stuff' but the fact of the matter is that I did add said stuff. Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

:::Edit:::

Forgot to mention that I have tried replacing 'new' with 'override' and ended up in a similar boat. Here are my errors with that change:

```
Error   7   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.RequiresUniqueEmail.set': cannot override because 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.RequiresUniqueEmail' does not have an overridable set accessor  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   78  13  EmptyMVC
Error   10  'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer.set': cannot override because 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer' does not have an overridable set accessor  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   122 13  EmptyMVC
Error   3   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression'   C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   28  35  EmptyMVC
Error   6   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.PasswordFormat': type must be 'System.Web.Security.MembershipPasswordFormat' to match overridden member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.PasswordFormat'   C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   61  32  EmptyMVC
Error   8   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.PasswordAttemptWindow.set': cannot override because 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.PasswordAttemptWindow' does not have an overridable set accessor  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   89  13  EmptyMVC
Error   5   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.MinRequiredPasswordLength.set': cannot override because 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.MinRequiredPasswordLength' does not have an overridable set accessor  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   56  13  EmptyMVC
Error   4   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters.set': cannot override because 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters' does not have an overridable set accessor    C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   45  13  EmptyMVC
Error   9   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts.set': cannot override because 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts' does not have an overridable set accessor    C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   100 13  EmptyMVC
Error   12  'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.EnablePasswordRetrieval.set': cannot override because 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.EnablePasswordRetrieval' does not have an overridable set accessor  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   144 13  EmptyMVC
Error   11  'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider.EnablePasswordReset.set': cannot override because 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.EnablePasswordReset' does not have an overridable set accessor  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   133 13  EmptyMVC
Error   1   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression.get'  C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
Error   2   'EmptyMVC.Controllers.ProfileProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.PasswordFormat.get' C:\Users\DigitalJedi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EmptyMVC\EmptyMVC\Controllers\ProfileController.cs   12  18  EmptyMVC
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `new` on your properties? This is not how you properly `override` members.

Comment: All of those errors describes exactly what is wrong and how to fix it. What are you asking us, exactly?

Comment: FYI - I updated my answer to address your new information, but it should be obvious what you need to do as @EricLippert says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `override` instead of `new` on your methods.  When you use `new` it creates a new method that hides an existing method of the same name in the base class, but doesn't actually implement that method.  Because the method is declared `abstract` in the base class you are required to implement it in any non-abstract inheriting class.  Using `override` informs the compiler that you are implementing the abstract method defined in the base class rather than replacing it as `new` would do.

**Edit**: The error messages that you get when you are using `override` are because the MembershipProvider doesn't implement the settors on those properties.  Remove the settors for those properties and your compiler errors will go away.  Likely you'll want to set the backing fields for those properties when the provider is created or configured.

I don't find the compiler errors generated to be either obscure or uninformative.  It should be obvious what is going on.  All you need to do is look at the documentation for the class you are implementing and you can see that there are no setters for the properties which have errors.

Comment: Ah, apologies - I did forget to mention that I tried that. I'll edit with THOSE errors too.

Comment: Actually, I think those errors are probably the only ones that matter.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 - might I suggest asking as a different question instead.  Changing this question now will invalidate this answer (and probably others).  A new question seems more appropriate.

Comment: Such was my assumption as well, just neglected to realize that I forgot to switch it back.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 - I just noticed that your class is named ProfileProvider, but implements MembershipProvider.  You know that your class name is in conflict both with the purpose of the class AND with the existing ProfileProvider framework class.